# How to tell printf() to get the value from the untyped (or byte-sequence) buffer

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I have a buffer of raw values, say, `void* buffer` or better, `char* buffer` - a raw byte stream, for example, read from a file. I'd like the bytes in the buffer to be represented and displayed in several ways, for example, as a `float`, or as a `long long` in runtime. I'd ask a user for desired format string, for example, `%10d`, and pass the format string to `printf()`. However, there are no format specifiers in `printf()` so it would expect an untyped (or byte-stream) buffer as a second argument?

How can I tell `printf()` to get the expected data from the buffer and display it according to the given format string? I won't like to use `switch-case` or `if-then` trees.

Comment: Read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack, before you want to stick with this design.

Comment: Yes, I know that passing the unfiltered user input is evil. I just provided this as an example of my needs.

Comment: is your serialization format (i.e. the format of what can go in your byte stream) fixed, or are you trying to come up with a serialization method? There's no way to do exactly what you're asking, but there might be a way of doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: First, I wonder why this approach is not implemented in printf()? I mean, to get the value from the buffer and to represent it accordint to format.
Second, I'm curious of what is the best way to implement this?
My byte stream has no pre-assumed format - it's like a part of a file header, which I'd like to allow the user to display it in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deserialize the bytestream into values. Both bytes and `float`s are non-text binary, but the translation between them still depends on endianness and, to be pedantic, whether the machine has IEEE FP math.

Once you've correctly read the bytes into native values, just use the regular format specifiers.

If you're sure that no byte translation is necessary, just cast `void*` to the desired `float*` or whatever, dereference the pointer, and print it as usual. But, that's very unportable and can crash on the wrong machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
void printUINT(const unsigned char *b,size_t bsize)
{
  size_t len=0;
  bsize-=sizeof(int);
  for(; len<=bsize; len+=sizeof(int));
    printf("%u\n",*(unsigned*)&b[len]);
}
void printULONG(const unsigned char *b,size_t bsize)
{
  size_t len=0;
  bsize-=sizeof(long);
  for(; len<=bsize; len+=sizeof(long));
    printf("%lu\n",*(unsigned long*)&b[len]);
}
void printDOUBLE(const unsigned char *b,size_t bsize)
{
  size_t len=0;
  bsize-=sizeof(double);
  for(; len<=bsize; len+=sizeof(double));
    printf("%f\n",*(double*)&b[len]);
}
```

Comment: no, I don't want to stick to switch-case with multiple print functions

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done without a `switch()`-type construction.  If `printf()` had such functionality, it would be implemented within the notional `switch() { }` block that handles the format specifiers, anyway.